# find the position of an element in an array with PFFile. Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, position

My below code works if orgArray is [String] and return a [String]. My question is how can I change it from String to PFFile like below. Below code has an error that highlighted `orgArray[count]` and `return tempArray`. Is there any way I can find the position of an element in an array with PFFile.

Thanks

```
func seperateArrayByTrueAndFalsePFFile (orgArray: [PFFile], arrayTrueFalse: [Bool], byBool: Bool) -> [PFFile] {
    var count: Int = 0
    var tempArray = [String]()
    while count != orgArray.count {
        if arrayTrueFalse[count] == byBool {
            tempArray.append(orgArray[count])
        }
        count += 1
    }
    return tempArray
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempArray` is initialized to be an array of String (`var tempArray = [String]()`) but you are returning it from your function which says it returns an array of type `[PFFile]`. That's one error.

`orgArray` is an array of `PFFile`s and you're trying to pull one of its elements to put it into `tempArray` which expects to receive a `String`. Type `String` and type `PFFile` are not interchangeable. Likewise type `[String]` and type `[PFFile]` are not interchangeable.

Comment: opps. Forgot to change the tempArray = [String]() to tempArray = [PFFile](). I'm so stupid. Anyways, thank you for your help.